# Dart: When to use a getter vs a final field

Tags: dart, design-patterns, getter, final

I have a simple question to ask.

Consider the two code examples,

```
// 1
class A {
  final a = 23;
}

// 2
class A {
  get a => 23;
}
```

in [2], the final field is converted into a getter.

question: Under which circumstances should either type of codes be used? Which one is the dart's preferred way?

Comment: AFAIK there is no real difference it's about personal preference, but you can read effective dart [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#do-use-getters-for-operations-that-conceptually-access-properties) and [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-using-a-final-field-to-make-a-read-only-property) about this topic; and I believe that in this case the example 1 it suggested to be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a preferred way. You can use either.
There is also not necessarily any difference in what they mean. A smart compiler can convert on to the other, depending on which is more efficient the way the class is used.

Assuming the compiler doesn't change the representation.

- The final field introduces a memory slot on each instance of the class which holds the value, and then a generic getter reading that slot.
- A getter introduces a getter method on the class, which does nothing except return the value.

Which is better depends on how the class is used. If you only have very few instances, then the memory overhead of the extra memory slot on each instance is negligible.

If the compiler is smart, it might skip the implicit getter for the field and read the slot directly.
If the compiler is smart, it might inline the explicit getter too.

All in all, I wouldn't worry about there being a difference.
I personally tend towards the getter, because I prefer to reason about the *state* of the object by looking at its fields, and the final constant-valued field doesn't really contribute to the state.

Answer (score 3):

In example 2, the value for `a` can change over time.

If you want to control a value but let other classes have access, you'll use a private variable with a public getter.

If the value will never change, you can consider const/final/static

Comment: The variable 'a' is meant to be 'final'. Then, what is the difference of that with example 2? The value of the getter is always 23, so how can it change over time?

Comment: It is legal to have `Example 2` decide that `a = 1000`. The getter will then always return 1000 from that point, until the variable is changed again. When you mark the variable as final, the compiler won't let you reassign the value anywhere else, because it knows that it's supposed to be `final`. I'll update my answer with some code to make it more clear

Comment: @loganrussell48 is wrong. There is no 'variable a' in example 2. It's a getter that always returns 23, so can't be changed.

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear and explicit, using the same terms as the Dart documentation: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters 
"properties". `a` is a *property*, not a *variable* like I previously said.

Answer (score 0):

##### When to use a `final` field:

Consider this class:

```dart
class Foo {
  // This final field can have just one value no matter how many times it is read.
  final int x = math.Random().nextInt(10); 

  // This getter will return different value each time it is read. 
  int get y => math.Random().nextInt(10);
}
```

##### When to use a getter:

In Flutter, if you change the value of a variable, the hot reload will not reflect this value but a getter will.